# Python how to get a list of color that used in one image

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

Python how to get a list of color that used in one image

I use PIL, and I want to have a dictionary of colors that are used in this image, including color(key) and number of pixel points it used.

How to do that?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have used something like the following a few times to analyze graphs:

```
>>> from PIL import Image
>>> im = Image.open('polar-bear-cub.jpg')
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> by_color = defaultdict(int)
>>> for pixel in im.getdata():
...     by_color[pixel] += 1
>>> by_color
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {(11, 24, 41): 8, (53, 52, 58): 8, (142, 147, 117): 1, (121, 111, 119): 1, (234, 228, 216): 4
```

Ie, there are 8 pixels with rbg value (11, 24, 41), and so on.

Comment: SO won't let me delete an accepted answer but this is obviously inferior to the `getcolors` method ;)

Comment: What would we do if we wanted to perform an operation (such as printing "Black pixel encountered!") each time we encountered a black pixel? Inside the `for pixel` loop would we do what could we put?

Answer (score 32):

The getcolors method should do the trick. See [the docs](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/image.htm#Image.getcolors).

**Edit**: That link is broken. Pillow seems to be the go-to lib now, forked from PIL. [New Docs](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/Image.html?highlight=getcolors#PIL.Image.Image.getcolors)

```
Image.open('file.jpg').getcolors() => a list of (count, color) tuples or None
```

Comment: hei i get kind a weird result: it returns an array of (int, int) tuple.. how can i get r,g,b from a single int?? ps: i have a gif file

Comment: You probably have a paletted image -- you can do im.convert() to convert the colors through the palette into a mode that lets you see all the bands

Comment: It's 7 years since I posted this answer, so hardly surprising. Pillow seems to be the go-to lib now, forked from PIL. http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/Image.html?highlight=getcolors#PIL.Image.Image.getcolors

Answer (score 12):

I'd like to add that the  .getcolors() function only works if the image is in an RGB mode of some sort.

I had this problem where it would return a list of tuples with (count, color) where color was just a number. Took me a while to find it, but this fixed it.

```
from PIL import Image
img = Image.open('image.png')
colors = img.convert('RGB').getcolors() #this converts the mode to RGB
```

Comment: I have an image open in RGBA mode and tried converting, but I still get `None` as a result, even though `img.show()` shows the picture with multiple colors.

Comment: Nevermind, the `maxcolors` argument will cause the function to return `None` if the number of colors is greater than the default of 256.  I just set it to an arbitrarily large value since I am not worried about overly large palettes (and am filtering them out by alpha values anyway).

Answer (score 7):

See https://github.com/fengsp/color-thief-py  "Grabs the dominant color or a representative color palette from an image. Uses Python and Pillow"

```
from colorthief import ColorThief

color_thief = ColorThief('/path/to/imagefile')
# get the dominant color
dominant_color = color_thief.get_color(quality=1)
# build a color palette
palette = color_thief.get_palette(color_count=6)
```

Answer (score 2):

`getcolors()` [returns](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.getcolors) `None` if number of colors in the image is greater than `maxcolor` argument. The function also works only with 'RGB' images. It's not very convenient.

`getdata()` on the other hand can be utilized in very convenient way together with [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter


colors = Counter(image.getdata())   # dict: color -> number

set(colors)                  # set of unique colors  
len(colors)                  # number of unique colors 
colors[(0, 0, 0)]            # black color frequency
max(colors, key=colors.get)  # most frequent color
```