# Using Python and Pillow, how can we count the number of unique colors in a PNG or JPG image?

Tags: python, png, jpeg, python-imaging-library

I am using Pillow to do some image operations and want to count how many unique colors are there in a PNG or JPG image file. I can do it easily with mode "P" images that have a small number of colors, but it won't work for RGB or RGBA images. Reading through the docs of Pillow, it seems that `Image.getcolors()` returns `None` if there are more than 256 colors.

What is the best way to do it? Can we do it using Pillow? I am targeting pure Python + Pillow, but I can optionally include numpy on my list of dependencies, it if it helps.

Comment: Loop through all the pixels and add them to a `set`?

Comment: The`Image.getcolors()` has a default maximum of 256, but you can change it as `Image.getcolors(maxcolors=1024)` or whatever you need.

Comment: Actually, if I open a JPEG photo, `Image.getcolors()` returns `None`, even if I call it with `maxcolors=`... Shouldn't it also work with RGB JPEG files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution (I encoded the PNG image in Base64):

```
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO
import base64

data = '''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'''

img = Image.open(BytesIO(base64.b64decode(data)))

unique_colors = set()
for i in range(img.size[0]):
    for j in range(img.size[1]):
        pixel = img.getpixel((i, j))
        unique_colors.add(pixel)

print('Image info = ', img)
print('Unique color count = ', len(unique_colors))
```

Prints:

```
Image info =  <PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile image mode=RGBA size=256x256 at 0x7FFFF670A400>
Unique color count =  7
```

Comment: It seems to work as expected. I hoped there could be some faster way to do it. But maybe this is as good as Pillow can go...

Comment: I was able to shave a few seconds on some big images using a set comprehension, that seems to run a bit faster: ```unique_colors = {img.getpixel((x,y)) for x in range(w) for y in range(h) }```

Comment: Too bad this question has been closed, new answers are not accepted, anyway this seems faster: `len(set(img.getdata()))`, see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/59709420/694360

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to list the pixel RGBs and scan through that? As John Anderson said, you can use Image.getcolors to get that. But to get the number of unique variables, you can convert it to a set, which removes duplicates, then get the length of that, with `len(set(list))`.

Comment: Yeah, that's the approach suggested by Andrej Kesey. And it seems to work as expected. I had hope to find some faster way to do it. But maybe that's as good as Pillow can go.